# CSS and JQuery errors for hovering a dynamic element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to creat a little menu, which gets positioned by hovering an element (will be shown between two elements). After that moving the mouse to the "X" will slideDown the menu, where some buttons are displayed. But the menu has some bugs for displaying and hovering. Also I don't like the code as I tried it. I think this could be done much more smarter...

**Update:** The behavior should be like this: If the cursor is on a .item, the menu should be displayed at the left corner - in the middle of two .item. The arrow should point to the space between these two .item. The menu just shows the "X"; the buttons are hidden. If the cursor points to the "X", then the buttons are shown (slideDown), so the user can click on these buttons. One problem for me is, that first (when just the "X" is shown) the width is just 25px. When displaying the buttons, the width changes, so the container has to expand to the left.

Please have a look here:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/b1gpd1n1/1/

**JS:**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.item', function( event ) {
    var left = $(this).offset().left - 50;
    $(".item_menu").css("left", left).css("top", $(this).offset().top - 15);
        $(".item_menu").hover(function() {
            var that = this;
            $(this).find('header').fadeOut(200);
            $(this).animate({'left': left-90, 'width': 120}, 200, function() {
                $(that).find('.buttons').slideDown(200);
            });

        }, function() { 
            $(this).animate({'left': left, 'width': 25}, 200);
            $(this).find('header').fadeIn(200);
            $(this).find('.body').slideUp(400); 
        });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="item_menu">
    <header>X</header>
    <div class="buttons"><button>Example</button></div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

I would be very glad if you could have a look at the code to improve it.

My problems:

1. Improve the arrow, which should be displayed at the right upper corner (with a little margin to the top)
2. Is there a better HTML-construct for the menu?
3. Hovering the menu makes some display-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many updates, [here I go](http://jsfiddle.net/b1gpd1n1/10/):

```
$(function(){
    var time = 400;
    var item = $(".item_menu");

    var item_width_button = item.width();
    $(".buttons button").hide();
    var item_width = item.width();

    var item_padding = item.css("padding");
    var pos = $(".item:first").offset();

    item.css({
        "right": ($(document).width() - pos.left) + "px",
        "top": (pos.top + $(".arrow").height()) + "px",
        "width": "0"
    });

    var now;
    $(".wrap .item").on("mouseenter", function(){
        now = $(this);
        show_item();
    });
    $("header").on("mouseenter", function(){
        show_buttons();
    });
    item.on("mouseleave", function(){
        show_item();
    });

    function show_item () {
        $(".buttons button").stop().slideUp(time, function(){
            item.show().stop().animate({
                "top": now.offset().top + "px",
                "width": item_width + "px",
                "padding": item_padding
            }, time);
        });
        $(".arrow").fadeIn(time);
    }

    function show_buttons(){
        item.animate({
            "width": item_width_button + "px",
        }, time, function(){
            $(".buttons button").stop().slideDown(time);
        });
        $(".arrow").fadeOut(time);
    }

});
```

Comment: As I think there is a misunderstanding for the behavior of the menu, I updated the post. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @user3142695 Check now if it is what you needed

Comment: As I need to position the menu really between two elements I would change it to `"top": now.offset().top - 20 + "px"`. But this would only work if the height of the items is always 40px . How can I calculate it for a variable item height?

Comment: It should work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/b1gpd1n1/12/ But as described in my comment above I need to calculate the position as the height of the items is variable. And why is the button 'jumping' right after jumping (FF)?

Comment: Do you mean this? _http://jsfiddle.net/b1gpd1n1/13/_ ... I'm not fluent in English, and I'm not understand what you want very well, I would recommend you ask a new question.. maybe others could help you

Comment: Thanks. But the button is still wobbling